# Mongodb scala driver decode case class with default values

Tags: mongodb, case-class, mongodb-scala

Is it possible some how to convince Mongodb driver to use default values for case class fields if no such field found?

Currently getting error:

```
case class TestMe(fieldname:String="defaultVal")

org.bson.BsonInvalidOperationException: Missing field: "fieldname"
```

P.S. I know that having it as a Option will not throw the error, bit next I will need to write extra code `getOrElse("...")` which I would like to avoid.

Comment: I have another problem but similar:
`case class TestMe(name: String, ar: Seq[String] = Seq.empty)`
if in the mongo I will add object with name field only I will get too `org.bson.BsonInvalidOperationException: Missing field: ar`

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the data you are trying to decode has the field. If you are not persisting the entire case class in your request to the db, it could be that you are (not) updating the field of the case class individually, and so a read on the data is failing because it is not optional.

I lost some time, and probably some sweat and hair due to the same error message